# Soma de itens em uma lista

Tags: python

Então, esse algoritmo que eu fiz não está fazendo a subtração que deve ser feita, preciso imprimir o total

```
#Essas variáveis são os valores que o usuário deve atingir no dia
#no caso se faltar ou execeder deve ser avisado.
prot_total = 140.0
carbo_total = 210.0
gordura_total = 56.0
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    nome, proteinas, carbos, gordura=input().split()
    if float(proteinas) > 140.0:
        proteinas -= prot_total

    if float(carbos) > 210.0:
        carbos -= carbo_total
        
    if float(gordura) > 56.0:
        gordura -= gordura_total
print(prot_total, "gramas de proteína em falta")
print(carbo_total, "gramas de carboidrato em falta")
print(gordura_total, "gramas de gordura em falta")
#Não está sendo feita a subtraçao
```

Estava tentando por uma função pra fazer isso, mas não consigo pensar em algo,
obrigado desde já.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom no primeiro trexo de código logo abaixo do input, temos uma condição

```
    if float(proteinas) > 140.0:
        proteinas -= prot_total
```

Ele não estar decrementando pois só irá decrementar **se o valor que você definiu no input for maior que o valor total** que no caso seria 141 ai sim ele faria subtração.

Vamos a melhoria que eu sugeriria para você:

```
# Mantenha essa váriaveis, para caso você queira mudar o valor total de consumo no dia sem
# Precisar alterar o código inteiro

prot_total = 140.0
carbo_total = 210.0
gordura_total = 56.0
```

Após definir isso no seu sitema você faz uma pergunta de quantos alimentos ele ingeriu, então para isso, vamos deixar mais claro o que está entrando no nosso sistema

```
qntd_alimentos = int(input("Informe a quantidade de alimentos: "))
```

Agora para termos salvo as quantidades totais vamos criar três novas váriaveis para salvar os valores totais

```
prot_total_usuario = 0.0
carbo_total_usuario = 0.0
gordura_total_usuario = 0.0
```

Agora vamos percorrer o loop que você definiu baseado na quantidade de alimentos informados, e vamos deixar mais claro que estamos informado ao sistema, e iremos adicionar esse valor informado ao valor total do usuário

```
for i in range(qntd_alimentos):
  proteina = float(input("Informe a quantidade de proteinas do alimento: "))
  carbo = float(input("Informe a quantidade de carbos do alimento: "))
  godura = float(input("Informe a quantidade de godura do alimento: "))

  prot_total_usuario += proteina
  carbo_total_usuario += carbo
  godura _total_usuario += godura
```

Quando o loop acabar veremos que todos os valores foram somados, (você pode usar um print para testar se quiser)

Agora que temos os valores totais, podemos fazer a verificação caso tenha excedido ou tenha ficado abaixo do esperado

```
if (prot_total_usuario == prot_total):
  print("Você atingiu o valor ideal!")
elif (prot_total_usuario < prot_total): 
  print(f"Você ficou abaixo do total de proteinas por {prot_total-prot_total_usuario}")
else:
   print(f"Você ficou acima do total de proteinas por {prot_total_usuario-prot_total}")

if (carbo_total_usuario == carbo_total):
  print("Você atingiu o valor ideal!")
elif (carbo_total_usuario < carbo_total): 
  print(f"Você ficou abaixo do total de carbo por {carbo_total-carbo_total_usuario}")
else:
   print(f"Você ficou acima do total de carbo por {carbo_total_usuario-carbo_total}")

if (gordura_total_usuario == carbo_total):
  print("Você atingiu o valor ideal!")
elif (gordura_total_usuario < carbo_total): 
  print(f"Você ficou abaixo do total de gordura por {gordura_total-gordura_total_usuario}")
else:
   print(f"Você ficou acima do total de proteinas por {gordura_total_usuario-gordura_total}")
```

Assim você cosnsegue ter o valor total informado pelo usuário e o qual foi a diferença do informado para o total esperado